# Setting Spring applicationContext properties from POM file

Tags: spring, maven

I have the following configurations in my applicationContext.xml file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>             
                <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="javaMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${smtp.host}" />
    </bean>
```

with smtp.host being set in my POM file like so:

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>

<profile>
    <id>local</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <application.env>local</application.env>
        <profile.scope>compile</profile.scope>
        <skip.test>true</skip.test>
        <smtp.host>my.smtp.server</smtp.host>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Upon deploying my application, I ran into an error message saying that Spring was not able to resolve smtp.host. I added the following mapping to my application.properties file:

```
smtp.host=${smtp.host}
```

But Spring started to complain that I had a circular placeholder reference on the property. Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You mix here two things up. The `pom.xml` is for building the application. Properties you define there has normally nothing to do with your application properties. And Maven profiles has nothing to do with Spring profiles. They are only named equaly.

You should configure your Spring Application as you can read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-environment). You could -- what I would not suggest -- use your pom as property source.

The normal way would be to read it from a externalized configuration. As I do not know if you use Spring Boot, you can have a look at the [Spring Boot Way](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and adapt it, if you use Spring without Boot.

So add a `apllication.properties` file into src/mein/resources like

```
smtp.host=my.smtp.server
```

If you use boot, you are done, else you have to add a

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
```

to your `@Configuration`

Answer (score 1):

Here you are mixing the build and runtime phase of application which are mutually exclusive.

Mavens' role end once the build is complete thus any properties used perishes with it. Moreover application start up is agnostic to the tool / process used to build it and thus there isn't any information shared between them. Thus the idea to use properties specified in `pom.xml` is not feasible.

Regarding the circular reference the statement `smtp.host=${smtp.host}` is loosely similar to java code `int i = i;` which essentially has no effect because `i` is defined and assigned to itself.

Comment: Thanks. The application that I'm working on actually already has some other properties getting set in a similar manner. From what I understand, what the code is trying to do is to get Maven to set some properties into application.properties and get Spring to read from the resulting properties file.

I've tried to extract the file generated in the final EAR file and it seems that some of the properties are getting set properly but some aren't (mostly the new ones).

Comment: In this case you need to manually scan all the maven goals in `pom.xml` being executed. It seems in one of the custom goal  the `application.properties` is written / copied from some location and then packaged  into EAR.